# URL rewriting gives a 500 Server error with my web.config file

Tags: php, iis-7, web-config, url-rewriting

I've used the code below to try and achieve clean URLs for my site search results. However, when I implemented it into my web.config file and upload it to my site I get a Server 500 Error. What did I do wrong?

There are a few URLS that I'm trying to clean, see links below:

> ```
> mydomain.com/dentists/zipcode/18954/us/
>
> mydomain.com/dentists/name/18954/us/the-persons-name/
>
> mydomain.com/dentists/phone/18954/us/3215558888
>
> mydomain.com/dentists/details/person-company-goes-here/
> ```

**This is what I have in my web.config file...**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Rewrite to store_locator_results.php">
                    <match url="^dentists/zipcode/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([_0-9a-z-]+)/([_0-9a-z-]+)/" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="store_locator_results.php?lat={R:1}&amp;lng={R:2}&amp;postcode={R:3}&amp;countryIso={R:4}&amp;businessname={R:5}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Rewrite to store_locator_results_by_name.php">
                    <match url="^dentists/name/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([_0-9a-z-]+)/([_0-9a-z-]+)/([_0-9a-z-]+)/" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="store_locator_results_by_name.php?lat={R:1}&amp;lng={R:2}&amp;postcode={R:3}&amp;countryIso={R:4}&amp;lastname={R:5}&amp;businessname={R:6}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Rewrite to store_locator_results_by_phone.php">
                    <match url="^dentists/phone/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([_0-9a-z-]+)/([_0-9a-z-]+)/" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="store_locator_results_by_phone.php?lat={R:1}&amp;lng={R:2}&amp;postcode={R:3}&amp;countryIso={R:4}&amp;phone={R:5}" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="Rewrite to store_locator_results.php">
                    <match url="^dentists/details/([0-9]+)/" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="store_info.php?store={R:1}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
            <outboundRules>
                <rule name="Rewrite to clean URL" preCondition="IsHTML">
                    <action type="Rewrite" value="/dentists/zipcode/{R:3}/{R:4}" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" value="/dentists/name/{R:3}/{R:4}/{R:5}/" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" value="/dentists/phone/{R:3}/{R:4}/{R:5}/" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" value="/dentists/details/{R:1}/" />
                </rule>
                <preConditions>
                    <preCondition name="IsHTML">
                        <add input="{RESPONSE_CONTENT_TYPE}" pattern="^text/html" />
                    </preCondition>
                </preConditions>
            </outboundRules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add following lines in `web.config` before `system.webServer` and within the `configuration` tag.

```
<configSections>
      <sectionGroup name="system.webServer">
           <sectionGroup name="rewrite">
                <section name="rewriteMaps" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
                <section name="rules" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
           </sectionGroup>
     </sectionGroup>
</configSections>
```

This will overwrite `mod_rewrite` rule in IIS.

Comment: This gives me an error: "The 'type' attribute must be specified on the 'section' tag. " What type should I use?

Comment: @SsjCosty I have worked on this long back. I think you need to use the new syntax. I hope section Default Configuration in [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228256(v=vs.85).aspx) might help.